# mainWindow not receiving data in electron js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-forge

So i was making a todo app using electron js.I wanted to send the todos once the window has loaded so i used

**main.js**

```
'use strict'

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const DataStore  = require('./DataStore');
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');

const todosData = new DataStore({ 'name':'Todo Mains'});
// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences:{
      nodeIntegration:true
    }
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  console.log(todosData.todos)

  mainWindow.once('dom-ready', () => {
    console.log('Dom is ready')
    mainWindow.webContents.send('todos',todosData.todos)
  });

};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
      
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
`
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
    const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
    
    ipcRenderer.on('todos',(event,todos) => {
      const todoList = document.getElementById('todo-Lists')
      if(!todoList){
        console.log('not there')
      }
      else{
        console.log(todoList)
        console.log('there')
      }
      const todoItems = todos.reduce((html,todo) => {
        html += "<li id='todo-items'>${todo}</li>"
        return html
      },'')

      todoList.innerHTML = todoItems()
    })
  
  </script>
  </html>
```

so now when the dom loads it should show right the todos?but it dosent.
when i used console.log(todosData.todos) in main.js it logs the todos from the json file into the terminal but it dosent log when logged from index.html.This shows that the data dosent get transfered from main.js to index.html.So can anyone help me with this?

Comment: So you're saying that neither "not there" nor "there" are in the browser window logs?

Comment: main.js logs in the terminal right? and an html page logs in the browser window.So by logging in main.js it logs in the terminal but dosent in browser window console in the developer tools.This only means that  data is not getting transferred from main.js to index.html

Comment: I've never experienced any issue with such mechanism. Can you please ensure that the `ipcRenderer` event is registered **BEFORE** the dom content is ready and that it effectively is registered and that no logs appear in the browser console?

Comment: I have added the import statement in the first line itself. const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron').I will send the whole code page of main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  mainWindow.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
    console.log('Dom is ready')
    mainWindow.webContents.send('todos',todosData.todos)
  });
```

There is no `dom-ready` event on BrowserWindow. This is an event on `webContents`